# Getting ImportError: no module named wsgi after changing settings

Tags: python, django

I have a django app deployed on Heroku.
I was using a single settings file which I had to change (mostly, changing the database) each time I had to run it locally or deploy it on Heroku.

I decided to change that and created a settings module (a settings folder with an `__init__.py` file) with different settings files (`development.py/production.py`) for different environment. I also changed the `manage.py` file to get the development settings file like this:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings.development")
```

And change `wsgi.py` to grab the production settings file:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings.development")
```

After I did that, the local development server is now running fine.
But when I deployed the code on Heroku, I get

> "ImportError: no module name wsgi"

error in heroku logs.

I have tried several things for the last few hours but all in vain.
Can somebody guide me what mistake I am making?
Thanks in advance.

Note: 'project' is the name of my project.

Comment: can you post your wsgi file and also it is in your project/project/ folder right?

Comment: Yes, it is in my project/project/ folder and here are the contents

`code`
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings.production")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from dj_static import Cling
application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
`code`

Comment: what about your Procfile?

Comment: web: gunicorn --pythonpath=./project  project.wsgi:application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 2 horrible struggling days, I figured that the culprit was **init**.py that I accidentally put into my project's main folder and Heroku was treating it as a module. Removing **init**.py solved the problem.